# Zip files and metadata

Tags: privacy, data-leakage, zip

I want to send a zip of some files. The files themselves don't contain anything sensitive but I'm wondering if zip files contain metadata that could identify me or something about me? It seems that zips save at least file timestamps. Is there anything else I need to be aware of? It wouldn't really matter but can anyone work out the program I created the zip on?

Answer (score 2):

You should be more concerned about the meta data of the files in the zip. Images often have geolocation and word documents can also have some juicy info. I'm sure a dedicated attacker could figure out what software you used to compress the file, but there's really no risk in that. Unless you're a VIP/high-value target, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Is there any concern with a zip of only text files? I'd still like to know more about what data a zip stores.

Comment: No. Zip files have an 'extra' field where the software that compresses it can store extra arbitrary meta data, perhaps software name or something, I don't think it's used often. Aside from that, txt files have no meta data as they are just raw bytes stored in a file.

Comment: @leaustinwile, re "extra field"; Which zipping tools leak info?